# How to reset my stack in react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have 5 tabs on my Home Screen.

- Home Tab
- Search tab
- AddPostTab
- Notifications Tab
- Profile Tab

AddPostTab is like this.

```
const AddPostTab = createStackNavigator({
    AddPost: {
      screen: AddPost,
    },
    ImageDescription: {
      screen: ImageDescription
    },
    },
    {
      headerMode:'none',
      mode:'modal'
    }
);
```

When I go back from `ImageDescription` screen to Home Screen and then if I go to `AddPostTab` again, I'm directly going to the `ImageDescription` screen. But I want to be able to go to AddPost screen.

I've also tried

```
 const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [
                    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AddPost' }),
                ],
              });
              this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

but this only takes me to the AddPost Screen. But if I use Home instead of AddPost, it doesn't works.
How can I reset my stack in my case so that I can go to Home screen?

Comment: it's not working to your HomeScreen because you dont have it associated with your stackNavigator. If you add your homeScreen to the stackNavigator you'll be able to navigate to it through the resetAction

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are completely different navigators. And `reset` can't be applied to TabNavigator, because it's not much sense to do it.
What you can do - is do something like this:

ImageDescription.js:

```
goToHome() => 
   this.props.navigation.popToTop() 
&& this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

This will reset to root your current stack and then you will switch to `Home` tab

Comment: Just to make myself clear, does this work on the basis of first statement to be true and then do the expression which is after `&&`?

Comment: @ShubhamBisht yes, it will execute exactly as you described. And unfortunately, I don't have experience with `react-native-camera` so I can't help there.

Comment: since I used your solution, now when I'm on my `HomeScreen`, sometimes my screen would navigate to `ImageDescription` out of nowhere. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: if i present a new fullscreen it's will not switch to Home

Answer (score 5):

if you are have a single stack then use this on button click

```
navigation.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
                index: 1,//the stack index
                routes: [
                    { name: 'Promote' },//to go to initial stack screen
                ],
            })
        )
```

for single stack you can also use the

```
navigation.popToTop()
```

but if you are wroking on tabs and then want to reset the tab then try this

```
 <BottomTab.Screen
    name="Post"
    component={PostStack}
    options={{
      unmountOnBlur: true,// set this props in your tab screen options
      title: 'Post',
      tabBarIcon: focused => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="Post" />,
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this from the screen you want to reset the stack with any event.

This fixed the similar issue for me (**React Navigation 5.x**)

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';

navigation.reset(
  [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Profile'})],
  0,
);
```